# Why doesn't DRF translate dutch?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

DRF automatically translates response messages for some languages if the right 'Accept-Language' header is present. It does this as expected for e.g. Spanish ('es') and French ('fr'), but apparently not for Dutch ('nl') even though all the necessary translations are [available](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/tree/master/rest_framework/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES).

DRF provides a way to [add new translations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/internationalization/#adding-new-translations). But since the translations are already made, this should not be necessary.

Django settings (no LANGUAGES setting):

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

Behaviour with other languages:

```sh
http http://localhost:8000/api/auth/password/reset/ Accept-Language:es

...
Content-Language: es
...

{
    "detail": "Método \"GET\" no permitido."
}
```

Behaviour with dutch:

```sh
http http://localhost:8000/api/auth/password/reset/ Accept-Language:nl

...
Content-Language: nl
...

{
    "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
}
```

Expected behaviour with dutch ([source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/django.po)):

```sh
http http://localhost:8000/api/auth/password/reset/ Accept-Language:nl

...
Content-Language: nl
...

{
    "detail": "Methode \"GET\" niet toegestaan."
}
```

django version: 2.1

djangorestframework version: 3.8.0

Comment: Perhaps this is a bug. You could try filing an issue over at their GitHub repo.

Comment: Just did. Thanks. https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6552